# Using API request to output MULTIPLE random JSON data to screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

Using the code below, I am able to retrieve user names from jsonplaceholder.com.

I am able to see **ALL** the user names using console.log, I cannot output **ALL** these items onscreen!

The output is only **ONE** of the array items.
Using `userName[0], userName[1]` outputs the same item?!
Using `userName[0].textContent = info[1];` outputs the first letter of a user name.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

```js
(function() {
  // set api addresses
  const usersJSON = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const commentsJSON = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

  // user function //
  // IIFE - get, parse, catch
  (function getData() {
    // get data
    fetch(usersJSON)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      //parse to json
      .then(function(data) {
        // user name
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          // generate random number 1 - 10
          var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
          displayName(data[num].name);
        }
      })

    // display user name
    function displayName(info) {
      const userName = document.getElementsByClassName("userName");

      for (let i = 0; i < userName.length; i++) {
        userName[0].textContent = info;
        userName[1].textContent = info;
      }
    }
  })();
})();
```

Comment: You're calling `displayName` multiple times, each time passing along a random username. `displayName` in turn puts that name into the first two `.userName` elements, so whatever the last name was is shown in both. Do you want this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rodz7jc9/

Comment: Replace the number with `i`: `userName[0].textContent`, and remove the second call. Also use `+=` or append a new element with the data. Using `=` you are overwriting your previous call.

Comment: @ChrisG - That is what it happening and it isn't what I want. I have 5 cards, each needing it's own name - from jsonplaceholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you might want to do is use an ID, and grab the item using `getElementById`, then you can remove the loop to make the function simpler (unless you have multiple classes you want to append the names to)

Your issue is that you are using `=`, which overwrites the previously set text/data, which is why you are seeing one item. You are adding the first item from the array, then on the next loop iteration you replace it with the next item in the array.

Here are two different solutions to fix your problem:

Use `+=` to append data instead of overwrite it:

```
function displayName(info) {
  const userName = document.getElementById("users");
  userName.innerHTML += '<p>' + info + '</p>';
}
```

Use `appendChild` to append data instead of overwrite it:

```
function displayName(info) {
  const userName = document.getElementById("users")
  const p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = info
  userName.appendChild(p)
}
```

```js
(function() {
  // set api addresses
  const usersJSON = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const commentsJSON = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

  // user function //
  // IIFE - get, parse, catch
  (function getData() {
    // get data
    fetch(usersJSON)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      //parse to json
      .then(function(data) {
        // user name
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          // generate random number 1 - 10
          var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
          displayName(data[num].name);
        }
      })

    // display user name
    function displayName(info) {
      const userName = document.getElementById("users");
        userName.innerHTML += '<p>' + info + '</p>';
    }
  })();
})();
```

```html
<div id="users"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect response! Thanks for the much needed help!